# Usefullness of the Announcer, Booster and Publicist badges?

Tags: feature-request, badges

I was a bit surprised by the [Announcer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/announcer), [Booster](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/58/booster) and [Publicist](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/publicist) badges.

[image: A snapshot of those three badges]

If I understood, those badges requires you to share links to questions with the form
`https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/[ID_of_the_question]/[your_id]`

I do think that I am constantly tracked on the net, and I don't think there is a need to overtrack my activities: if I want to share a link, I do not see why [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com) should know that **I, personally**, shared this link.

Plus, I guess that those badges could be easily won by a (ill-intentioned) person that artificially produces *fake* visits, for instance by DDOSing [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

So no, this is not exactly a feature-request, more like "feature-delet-request".

Of course, I am still free to ignore those badges `;-)`.

Comment: I have to say I always remove the `<your_id>` part :-) I've never really seen the benefit of them as a result!

Comment: By the way, what's the actual question here?

Comment: @JosephWright that's why you haven't got as much gold as Stefan:-)

Comment: The idea was probably, in case something went viral, to find out, who shared the link and where etc. In return you get a counter increase in the yellow dots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to your track your links and to match them with your account. StackExchange just needs that tracking to reward your links if you like, if you used that feature.

As Jay said in a [StackOverflow blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/), "people will do anything for fake internet points", and also the mentioned badges are such "achievements". Well, kidding, it's about helping people, he said.

Good content, moderation tasks, and promotional work of users is encouraged by points and badges, that's why also promotion badges exist.

Comment: The point is that I do not think that "StackExchange needs that tracking", but I understood why it's been proposed, even if I disagree.

Answer (score 5):

You can just copy the link of the question title

[image]

This is similar to copying the link directly from the browser hyperlink bar.

This option includes the question title in the URL, with the format

```
http://*.stackexchange.com/<post type>/<post id>/<post title>
```

and is void of any reference to you personally.

Comment: Yes, I know I could just bypass this feature, what I did not understood was *why* Sxe offers it. I see it as an intrusion in my privacy.